# Getting errors in connecting with AWS when using from windows 7

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to connect with DynamoDb from my laptop which has operating system windows7. But i get following error when i run the simple python script for creating a table in dynamodb. What i got from error is that it is some connectivity issue. Snapshot is attached showing the errors, if anyone has idea then please share.

```
File "/home/name/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto3/resources/factory.py", line 520, in do_action
response = action(self, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/name/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto3/resources/action.py", line 83, in __call__
    response = getattr(parent.meta.client, operation_name)(**params)

File "/home/name/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 159, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
File "/home/name/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 483, in _make_api_call
    operation_model, request_dict)
File "/home/name/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 141, in make_request
    return self._send_request(request_dict, operation_model)
File "/home/name/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 170, in _send_request
    success_response, exception):
File "/home/name/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 249, in _needs_retry
    caught_exception=caught_exception, request_dict=request_dict)
File "/home/name/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/hooks.py", line 227, in emit
    return self._emit(event_name, kwargs)
File "/home/name/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/hooks.py", line 210, in _emit
    response = handler(**kwargs)
File "/home/name/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 183, in __call__
    if self._checker(attempts, response, caught_exception):
File "/home/name/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 251, in __call__
    caught_exception)
File "/home/name/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 277, in _should_retry
    return self._checker(attempt_number, response, caught_exception)
File "/home/name/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 317, in __call__
    caught_exception)
File "/home/name/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 223, in __call__
    attempt_number, caught_exception)
File "/home/name/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 359, in _check_caught_exception
    raise caught_exception
botocore.vendored.requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', error(111, 'Connection refused'))
```

Python Code

```
import boto3

# Get the service resource.
dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')

# Create the DynamoDB table.
table = dynamodb.create_table(
    TableName='users',
    KeySchema=[
        {
            'AttributeName': 'username',
            'KeyType': 'HASH'
        },
        {
            'AttributeName': 'last_name',
            'KeyType': 'RANGE'
        }
    ],
    AttributeDefinitions=[
        {
            'AttributeName': 'username',
            'AttributeType': 'S'
        },
        {
            'AttributeName': 'last_name',
            'AttributeType': 'S'
        },

    ],
    ProvisionedThroughput={
        'ReadCapacityUnits': 5,
        'WriteCapacityUnits': 5
    }
)

# Wait until the table exists.
table.meta.client.get_waiter('table_exists').wait(TableName='users')

# Print out some data about the table.
print(table.item_count)
```

[errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RVLEt.jpg)

Comment: can you provide what is the error? and what is your script?

Comment: Can you provide the stack trace as *text* and not as a *image*? It is *far* easier to search than manually copying the content of the image, and as such improve *dramatically* your chances of getting a quick answer

Comment: @Ali please find below the error

Comment: Can you please show your code? Are you trying to connect to local DynamoDB or remote AWS?

Comment: @notionquest please check the code , i am trying to connect with remote AWS.

Comment: Can you set the region and try ? Example: dynamodb = boto3.resource("dynamodb", region_name='us-west-2'). Please ensure you set your region. Just don't go with 'us-west-2'..

Comment: I check that and still the same error.

Comment: Problem is solved. I have added the http and https proxy in environment variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is solved. I have added the http and https proxy in environment variable.